# CString Format() unable to read memory VS2015

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015, c-strings

I'm keep receiving the message `Error reading characters of string` `Unable to read memory`. I'm not sure how to correct it as it seems like everything is in order when the CString.Format() function is called.

Here is the spot in strnlen.cpp where the error occurs:
[image]

And here are the Locals at the time of the break:
[image]

This is the function that is calling strnlen.cpp (the last line is where the break occurs):

```
char comp[50];
gethostname(comp,50);

CString textmsg;
textmsg.Format("%s %s: %s",TEXT,comp, m_edit_message);
```

m_edit_message is a CString variable.

Lastly here is the call stack at the time of the error:

```
NetChess.exe!common_strnlen_c<unsigned char>(const unsigned char * const string, const unsigned int maximum_count) Line 36  C++
NetChess.exe!common_strnlen_simd<0,unsigned char>(const unsigned char * const string, const unsigned int maximum_count) Line 94 C++
NetChess.exe!common_strnlen<unsigned char>(const unsigned char * const string, const unsigned int maximum_count) Line 153   C++
NetChess.exe!strnlen(const char * string, unsigned int maximum_count) Line 165  C++
NetChess.exe!__crt_stdio_output::output_processor<char,__crt_stdio_output::string_output_adapter<char>,__crt_stdio_output::standard_base<char,__crt_stdio_output::string_output_adapter<char> > >::type_case_s_compute_narrow_string_length(const int maximum_length, char __formal) Line 2268  C++
NetChess.exe!__crt_stdio_output::output_processor<char,__crt_stdio_output::string_output_adapter<char>,__crt_stdio_output::standard_base<char,__crt_stdio_output::string_output_adapter<char> > >::type_case_s() Line 2255  C++
NetChess.exe!__crt_stdio_output::output_processor<char,__crt_stdio_output::string_output_adapter<char>,__crt_stdio_output::standard_base<char,__crt_stdio_output::string_output_adapter<char> > >::state_case_type() Line 1999  C++
NetChess.exe!__crt_stdio_output::output_processor<char,__crt_stdio_output::string_output_adapter<char>,__crt_stdio_output::standard_base<char,__crt_stdio_output::string_output_adapter<char> > >::process() Line 1644  C++
NetChess.exe!common_vsprintf<__crt_stdio_output::standard_base,char>(const unsigned __int64 options, char * const buffer, const unsigned int buffer_count, const char * const format, __crt_locale_pointers * const locale, char * const arglist) Line 163  C++
NetChess.exe!__stdio_common_vsprintf(unsigned __int64 options, char * buffer, unsigned int buffer_count, const char * format, __crt_locale_pointers * locale, char * arglist) Line 235  C++
NetChess.exe!_vscprintf_l(const char * const _Format, __crt_locale_pointers * const _Locale, char * _ArgList) Line 1655 C++
NetChess.exe!_vscprintf(const char * const _Format, char * _ArgList) Line 1672  C++
[External Code] 
NetChess.exe!CMessageSend::OnOK() Line 60   C++
NetChess.exe!_AfxDispatchCmdMsg(CCmdTarget * pTarget, unsigned int nID, int nCode, void(CCmdTarget::*)() pfn, void * pExtra, unsigned int nSig, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo) Line 77  C++
NetChess.exe!CCmdTarget::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID, int nCode, void * pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo) Line 372   C++
NetChess.exe!CDialog::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID, int nCode, void * pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo) Line 85   C++
NetChess.exe!CWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 2779    C++
NetChess.exe!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message, unsigned int wParam, long lParam, long * pResult) Line 2092   C++
NetChess.exe!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 2078 C++
NetChess.exe!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd, HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 265   C++
NetChess.exe!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 418    C++
[External Code] 
NetChess.exe!CWnd::IsDialogMessageA(tagMSG * lpMsg) Line 193    C++
NetChess.exe!CWnd::PreTranslateInput(tagMSG * lpMsg) Line 4586  C++
NetChess.exe!CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 80    C++
NetChess.exe!CWnd::WalkPreTranslateTree(HWND__ * hWndStop, tagMSG * pMsg) Line 3358 C++
NetChess.exe!AfxInternalPreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 233 C++
NetChess.exe!CWinThread::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 777    C++
NetChess.exe!AfxPreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg) Line 252 C++
NetChess.exe!AfxInternalPumpMessage() Line 178  C++
NetChess.exe!CWinThread::PumpMessage() Line 900 C++
NetChess.exe!CWinThread::Run() Line 629 C++
NetChess.exe!CWinApp::Run() Line 787    C++
NetChess.exe!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 47   C++
NetChess.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 26  C++
[External Code]
```

MessageSend.cpp

```
// MessageSend.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "NetChess.h"
#include "MessageSend.h"
#include "NetChessDoc.h"
#include "NetChessView.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

//////////////////////////////////////////////////// CMessageSend dialog

bool BoundsCheck2(char *myTestArray, unsigned int expectedSize);

CMessageSend::CMessageSend(CWnd* pParent)
    : CDialog(CMessageSend::IDD, pParent)
{
    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CMessageSend)
    m_edit_message = _T("");
    m_edit_receive_message = _T("");
    //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
}
void CMessageSend::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CMessageSend)
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_MESSAGE, m_edit_message);
    DDV_MaxChars(pDX, m_edit_message, 50000);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_RECEIVE_MESSAGE, m_edit_receive_message);
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMessageSend, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMessageSend)
    ON_WM_VSCROLL()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
//////////////////////////////////////CMessageSend message handlers
void CMessageSend::OnOK() 
{
    //msgDlg.m_edit_send_message
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    char comp[50];
    if (BoundsCheck2(comp, 50))
        gethostname(comp,50);

    CString textmsg;
    textmsg.Format("%s %s: %s",TEXT,comp, (CString) m_edit_message);

    m_edit_receive_message += (CString)comp + ": " + m_edit_message +  (CString)"\r\n";;
    ((CNetChessView*)((CFrameWnd*)(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd))->GetActiveView())->SendSockData((unsigned char*)textmsg.GetBuffer(0),textmsg.GetLength());
    //textmsg.ReleaseBuffer(0); 
    m_edit_message = "";
    UpdateData(FALSE);
    CWnd* wnd= GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_RECEIVE_MESSAGE);
    wnd->PostMessage(WM_VSCROLL,SB_BOTTOM,0);
    //CDialog::OnOK();
}
void CMessageSend::SetReceiveData(char* data)
{
    m_edit_receive_message += (data + (CString)"\r\n");
    UpdateData(FALSE);
    CWnd* wnd= GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_RECEIVE_MESSAGE);
    wnd->PostMessage(WM_VSCROLL,SB_BOTTOM,0);
}
void CMessageSend::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar) 
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

    CDialog::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}

bool BoundsCheck2(char *myTestArray, unsigned int expectedSize)
{
    //Reference: Reference: http://lelanthran.com/deranged/?p=182
    bool status = true;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    //perform bounds checkes on data1; just to be safe
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(myTestArray) / sizeof(myTestArray[0]); i++)     {
        count++;
    }
    if (count <= expectedSize)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;
    return status;
}
```

MessageSend.h

```
#if !defined(AFX_MESSAGESEND_H__08C3FB4D_9E1E_4AF9_951F_7ED1033E3B16__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_MESSAGESEND_H__08C3FB4D_9E1E_4AF9_951F_7ED1033E3B16__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000
// MessageSend.h : header file
//

///////////////////////////////////////////CMessageSend dialog

class CMessageSend : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CMessageSend(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
    void SetReceiveData(char* data);
    // standard constructor
// Dialog Data
    //{{AFX_DATA(CMessageSend)
    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG_MESSAGE };
    CString m_edit_message;
    CString m_edit_receive_message;
    //}}AFX_DATA

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    virtual void OnOK();
    afx_msg void OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

#endif //     !defined(AFX_MESSAGESEND_H__08C3FB4D_9E1E_4AF9_951F_7ED1033E3B16__INCLUDED_)
```

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: What is `TEXT`? How is it initialized? What is `m_edit_message`? How is it initialized? Did the call to `gethostname` succeed? My *guess* is that either `TEXT` or `m_edit_message` is not plain old C-string pointer (or array) but something like a `CString` object which can't really be used without explicit cast to a C-style string pointer.

Comment: Also what is `it`? Please try to create reproducible error with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't know what `it` is, that's a variable being created/used by VS

Comment: The problem with showing that location where the crash happens is that it's inside the standard library code, and that code works. The problem is in your code, the code and variables inside the library is irrelevant.

Comment: [This text should tell you all you need to know.](http://mfctips.com/2012/03/23/cstringformat-s-cstring-argument-garbage-text/)

Comment: it was that TEXT argument. It was of type Action::TEXT. Not sure what my peers intention was with that but now that I know the problem I can ask...thanks!

Comment: I was mistaken, `it` is irrelevant as Joachim said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you have in your code, this code:

```
bool BoundsCheck2(char *myTestArray, unsigned int expectedSize)
// ...
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(myTestArray) / sizeof(myTestArray[0]); i++)     {
    count++;
}
```

is not doing what you think, `sizeof(myTestArray) / sizeof(myTestArray[0]` is equal to 8 - always (well on 32bit is would be 4 - size of pointer), this is because when you call a function with array argument it decays to pointer to its first element and the size of array is lost.

Its also hard to tell what this function is supposed to do, is it checking whether compiler created 50 element array? You better zero initialize it before use.

Another thing: check if you are compiling with UNICODE enabled, if so then  CString is of `wchar_t` character type.

This code:

```
CString textmsg;
textmsg.Format("%s %s: %s",TEXT,comp, (CString) m_edit_message);
```

I would rewrite as:

```
CString textmsg;
textmsg.Format("%s %s: %s",TEXT.GetString(), comp, m_edit_message.GetString());
```

assuming TEXT is of type CString - I suppose it is bound to some widget?

also:

```
char comp[50];
```

as:

```
char comp[256] = {0};
```

why 256, read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/ms738527(v=vs.85).aspx

last thing, always check result codes for Win API functions, otherwise you might use returned data in undetermined state.

Comment: With this function I was trying to ensure that the variable passed to `myTestArray` does not exceed the array size `expectedSize`. Therefore ensuring a `bufferoverlow` could not occur

Comment: @Chris - this function always returns true ( 8 < 50 ),

Comment: I am using UNICODE, I will implement your suggestion above tonight. Also changed the check to `(size_t i = 0; i <= sizeof(myTestArray))`